# What's wrong with UserDefaultCredentials

Tags: .net, asp.net, security

I'm using Exchange Web Service exposed from exchange 2007 SP1 server to create emails from my application and I've encounted a problem I can't figure out.

I get this response "When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids." everytime I try to `CreateItem()` from a web application.

This only happens on a Windows 2003 + IIS6 when `UseDefaultCredentials = True`. But it's fine if I set the credentials with `New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","password")`. The latter is not an option in production.

The strangest thing is that `UseDefaultCredentials = True` works if I run it from VS2008 on my local machine (but the exchange server is the same remote machine). What is wrong?

To make this more readable I've pasted a code example that uses Exchange WS API 1.0 here below. But it's the same problem if I use the Exchange WS directly.

```
    Dim serviceObj As ExchangeService = _
        New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
    serviceObj.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    serviceObj.Url = New Uri(serviceUrl)
    Dim message = New EmailMessage(serviceObj)
    message.Subject = "Greetings"
    message.Body = New MessageBody(BodyType.Text, "Hello World")
    message.ToRecipients.Add("example@domain.com")
    message.SendAndSaveCopy()
```

Thankful for any thoughts.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was solved by using Impersonation.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. There is no explanation of what impersonation is or how it is the correct solution or how to even use it. Now someone has to post another question asking how to actually use the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a desktop app or a web app? If it's the latter perhaps DefaultCredentials is using the app pool identity?

What happens if you use:

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

And UseDefaultCredentials as false?

Comment: DefaultCredentials can't be casted to ExchangeCredentials - I used DefaultNetworkCredentials instead. But it gave the same result. (When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids)

Comment: Is it a web app or a desktop app?

Comment: What authentication mode(s) have you got it in?

Comment: Only Windows Integrated authentication.